# How to get svn remote repository URL?

Tags: svn

I have an svn working copy on my local system. I want to get the remote repository URL. Is there some command for doing this?

Comment: When you say 'workspace' do you mean you're using SVN integrated into some IDE e.g. Eclipse? Either way Grhm's command-line solution will work, provided you have the command-line tools installed too though.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Try:

```
svn info .
```

This should give some information about the current working copy, including the remote URL.

From [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html), an example output is:

```
$ svn info foo.c  
Path: foo.c  
Name: foo.c  
URL: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/foo.c  
Repository Root: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test  
Repository UUID: 5e7d134a-54fb-0310-bd04-b611643e5c25  
Revision: 4417  
Node Kind: file  
Schedule: normal  
Last Changed Author: sally  
Last Changed Rev: 20  
Last Changed Date: 2003-01-13 16:43:13 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)  
Text Last Updated: 2003-01-16 21:18:16 -0600 (Thu, 16 Jan 2003)  
Properties Last Updated: 2003-01-13 21:50:19 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)  
Checksum: d6aeb60b0662ccceb6bce4bac344cb66
```

Comment: The accepted answer should integrated the answer from Sam Buchmiller: `svn info --show-item=url --no-newline`

Answer (score 21):

As of Subversion 1.9 you can now request a specific item from svn info.

```
svn info --show-item=url
```

This will output only the remote url. To get rid of the newline at the end, add this extra option:

```
svn info --show-item=url --no-newline
```

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
svn info | grep URL | sed  's/URL: //g'
```

Comment: You can also make that `svn info | sed -ne 's/URL: //p'` and save the `grep`; the `-n` and `p` mean only print matching lines

Comment: `svn info | grep ^URL | tail -c+6` =)

Comment: This command also gives me the relative URL, so I had to pipe it through head like this: `svn info | grep URL | sed 's/URL: //g' | head -1` to get just the URL.

Answer (score 3):

`svn info | grep 'URL' | awk '{print $NF}'`

where awk $NF prints only the last column in a record

Answer (score 1):

```
svn info | grep ^URL: | sed  's/URL: //g'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Tortoise SVN . Just Right click inside your SVN repo and look for "repo browser". Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers. When you want to get the repository URL of your working copy, you can run the following PowerShell snippet:

```
([xml](svn info --xml)).info.entry.URL
```