# SVN: list all branches of all projects in a respository

Tags: windows, svn, branch

I have SVN repository setup and it has somewhat around 15 different projects. Each project has a similar structure i.e.

```
ProjectOne/
          tags/
          branches/
          trunk/
```

now, what I want to do is somehow list all the branches for all the projects in the repository. 
Is there a command or something I could use to do this? or going programmatically is the only option here ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the answer you're looking for:

```
svn ls URL-OF-REPO
```

and to find the REPO URL (If you don't know it already), you can use:

```
svn info .
```

inside the "current" SVN directory.

Alternatively, and more complicatedly, you can CLI-program the output to regex the URL too, as suggested in another posting:

```
svn info | grep URL | sed  's/URL: //g'
```

---

See these other StackOverflow posts for more information. Hope this helps!

1. [How to list all files in a remote SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646798/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-remote-svn-repository)
2. [How to get svn remote repository URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128344/how-to-get-svn-remote-repository-url)

Answer (score 0):

There is [`svn list`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) command. Since you already know the URLs of your repositories and projects, just run it like this `svn info https://svn.example.com/MyProject1/branches`.

You could automate it using PowerShell. Here are two rough examples.

- Use [`foreach` loop](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847816.aspx) to automate running `svn list`:

  ```
  $repos = "MyProject1", "MyProject2", "MyProject3", "MyProject4", "MyProject5"
  $rootURL = "https://svn.example.com/"

  foreach ($repo in $repos) {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Repository: $rootURL/$repo `nBranches:"
  svn list $rootURL/$repo/branches
  }
  ```
- Use [xml'ed output of `svn list`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml) and parse the output with [`Select-XML`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx). You could customize the command to get latest revision, author and date&time.

  ```
  $repos = "MyProject1", "MyProject2", "MyProject3", "MyProject4", "MyProject5"
  $rootURL = "https://svn.example.com/"

  foreach ($repo in $repos) {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Repository: $rootURL/$repo `nBranches:"
  ([xml](svn list $rootURL/$repo/branches --xml)).SelectNodes("//lists/list/entry").Name
  }
  ```

Note that both script samples will display only the branches that exist in HEAD (i.e. latest) revision.