# How can I get in Intellij the SVN Link of a file without SVN browser?

Tags: url, intellij-idea, svn

You can get the URL in the Intellij SVN Browser. But it's awkward. 
Is there a possibility to get the SVN link of a file, without the SVN browser, i.e. over the Intellij file context menu?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67176 . As a workaround you could use "Subversion > Relocate..." action.

Comment: Write this as answer and I vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User y.bedrov wrote it's not directly possible. I think it's right :((

But there is a simple walk around.

1. Open filecontext menu + copy path
2. Open shell and run the following command `svn info --show-item=url FILEPATH`

s. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190272/1514029

or

1. Open filecontext menu + Subversion + relocate
2. Copy SNV URL from "From URL:"

(thanks y.bedrov + Dmitry Cherniachenko from IDEA)

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted and remember to update it when this request gets resolved https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67176

Comment: IMHO  "Subversion > Relocate..."  is a faster workaround